# How to avoid cross join

Tags: sql, db2

I'm working on query which gives me history of records in db2 using 
"FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM  '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' TO '9999-12-30-00.00.00.000000000000'".

Steps performed :
1) Added a record in 'NAME_TABLE' which contains 'SAMPLE_NAME' column.
2) Set the pk of the 'NAME_TABLE' as foreign key(NAME_FK) in another table called 'PREF_TABLE'.
3) Now, deleted that name from 'NAME_TABLE'. This results in deleting records from both the tables.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting cross join result. 
Please help me to avoid cross joining.

```
Below are the transaction times for two actions performed.(insert and delete)

NAME_TABLE              PREF_TABLE                
15-Oct-2019 01:24:07    15-Oct-2019 01:24:17 
15-Oct-2019 01:24:34    15-Oct-2019 01:24:17
15-Oct-2019 01:24:07    15-Oct-2019 01:24:34
15-Oct-2019 01:24:34    15-Oct-2019 01:24:34 

Inserted into NAME_TABLE at 15-Oct-2019 01:24:07
Inserted into PREF_TABLE at 15-Oct-2019 01:24:17
deleted from both the tables at 15-Oct-2019 01:24:34
```

```sql
   SELECT SAMPLE_NAME
   FROM PREF_TABLE FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM  '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' TO 
   '9999-12-30-00.00.00.000000000000' PREN
   INNER JOIN NAME_TABLE FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM  '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' TO 
   '9999-12-30-00.00.00.000000000000' PN ON PN.PK = PREN.NAME_FK
```

I expect the output of only two records i.e., for inserting and deleting.
But I'm getting 4 records instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE NAME_TABLE
(
 PK           INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 SAMPLE_NAME  INT,
 sys_start    TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW BEGIN,
 sys_end      TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
 ts_id        TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS TRANSACTION START ID,
 PERIOD SYSTEM_TIME (sys_start, sys_end)
) IN USERSPACE1;

CREATE TABLE NAME_TABLE_HIST LIKE NAME_TABLE IN USERSPACE1;
ALTER TABLE NAME_TABLE ADD VERSIONING USE HISTORY TABLE NAME_TABLE_HIST;

CREATE TABLE PREF_TABLE
(
 FK           INT NOT NULL,
 SAMPLE_NAME  INT,
 sys_start    TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW BEGIN,
 sys_end      TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
 ts_id        TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS TRANSACTION START ID,
 PERIOD SYSTEM_TIME (sys_start, sys_end),
 CONSTRAINT PREF_TABLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (FK) REFERENCES NAME_TABLE (PK) ON DELETE CASCADE
) IN USERSPACE1;

CREATE TABLE PREF_TABLE_HIST LIKE PREF_TABLE IN USERSPACE1;
ALTER TABLE PREF_TABLE ADD VERSIONING USE HISTORY TABLE PREF_TABLE_HIST;


INSERT INTO NAME_TABLE (PK, SAMPLE_NAME) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO PREF_TABLE (FK, SAMPLE_NAME) VALUES (1, 1);

-- No rows in both tables
SELECT * FROM NAME_TABLE_HIST;
SELECT * FROM PREF_TABLE_HIST;

DELETE FROM NAME_TABLE;

-- One row in both tables
SELECT * FROM NAME_TABLE_HIST;
SELECT * FROM PREF_TABLE_HIST;

-- SELECT statement returns 1 row
SELECT PN.SAMPLE_NAME
FROM PREF_TABLE 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM  '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' TO '9999-12-30-00.00.00.000000000000' 
PREN
JOIN NAME_TABLE 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM  '0001-01-01-00.00.00.000000' TO '9999-12-30-00.00.00.000000000000' 
PN ON PN.PK = PREN.FK;
```

When you insert into a system temporal table, no rows inserted into the history table.
There are no duplicates so far.
You may have them, of course, if you insert / update the rows with the same ID in addition, but you should change the description of your sequence of steps to reproduce the problem and describe the desired result.
If you want to avoid duplicates, you may want to use
`FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF 'timestamp_constant'` (a "snapshot" of table contents at this time)
instead of
`FOR SYSTEM_TIME FROM 'timestamp_constant1' TO 'timestamp_constant2'`.
If you use the latter, I believe you should understand, that if you get more that one version of the same row, then it's expected to have such duplicates in the result set.